# MVC - Action passing to wrong controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor

I have a form that submits a SearchByUserViewModel (containing only `string ID`) to `asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SubmitUserSearch"`. The form is a single textbox and a submit button. `SubmitUserSearch` retrieves the ID from the model and returns `RedirectToAction("EventListByArtist", m.ID)`.

EventListByArtist, in the Home controller, is as follows:

```
    public IActionResult EventListByArtist(string ID)
    {
        var events = context.Events.ToList();
        ViewBag.genres = context.Genres.ToList();
        ViewBag.artists = context.Artists.ToList();
        ViewBag.ID = ID;
        return View("EventList", events);
    }
```

SubmitUserSearch redirects to EventListByArtist:

```
    public IActionResult SubmitUserSearch(SearchByUserViewModel m)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("EventListByArtist", m.ID);
    }
```

The SearchByUserViewModel contains only the ID field.

However, something in the middle breaks, and instead of being directed to (for example input "Bob") `Home/EventListByArtist/Bob`, I am directed to `Bob/EventListByArtist`, which does not exist. What is causing this redirect? The form has been pasted below.

```
<form asp-controller="Home" asp-action="SubmitUserSearch" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]" class="form-horizontal">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="ID" class="col-md-2 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <input asp-for="ID" class="form-control" id="artistInput" />
            <span asp-validation-for="ID" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

The project routes declaration (in Startup.cs) is as follows:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: Where is your `IActionResult` is it in the Home Controller?

Comment: Post your routes. It might be beneficial to see the definition of `SubmitUserSearch` as well.

Comment: Yes, the action is in the Home controller. Routes added, will add definition of SubmitUserSearch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SubmitUserSearch()` POST method the value of `m.ID` is a `string` ("Bob") so you `RedirectToAction()` translates to

```
return RedirectToAction("EventListByArtist", "Bob");
```

which is using [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.RedirectToAction%28System.String,System.String%29) where the 2nd parameter is the name of the controller, hence it generates `/Bob/EventListByArtist`.

You need to use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Controller.RedirectToAction%28System.String,System.Object%29) where the 2nd parameter is `object`

```
return RedirectToAction("EventListByArtist", new { id = m.ID });
```